# Counting entries in mysql which are not equal to something

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am making this code to count the entries in a database in which a column's default value will be specified by me. In the front end, user can change the value of that column to a random alphanumeric number. Now I have to count how many entries has the user changed. I tried the following code(s) in jdbc while linking mysql to it:

```
select * from complaints where RID=11120059 where permanent_token !='0';
select * from complaints where RID=11120059 where not permanent_token ='0';
```

but none is working. I am giving default value of varchar to permanent_token as '0'.

Comment: OMG ! You are using two `where` clauses?

Comment: you could simply use the [count function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

Comment: `select * from complaints where RID=11120059 where permanent_token <> '0';`, but if you only wanted to know the number of entries that match your query you could simply use `select count(*) from complaints where RID=11120059 where permanent_token <> '0';`  I'd also recommend the use of `PreapredStatement`s, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is two mistakes in your requests.

- First, you use twice the keyword `where`
- Second, when you want something not equals in sql you have to use `<>`

For exemple, your first request:
`select * from complaints where RID=11120059 and permanent_token <>'0';`

and to have your count result:
`select count(*) from complaints where RID=11120059 and permanent_token <>'0';`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You are using 2 `where` clauses in your query. Even after you removed the extra `where` clause, you have to execute two queries to get the count of each.

**Solution:**

This will give you the total number of records within in one query.

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN permanent_token = '0' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as NotZeroCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN permanent_token = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as IsZeroCount
from complaints 
where RID=11120059
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by trying to say your query out loud, "get me all the records from complaints where RID equals 11120059 AND permanent_token is not equal to 0", which might translate to something like...

```
select * from complaints where RID=11120059 and permanent_token <> '0';
```

Will return all the records which match your query, if you only wanted to know the number of entries that match your query you could simply use

```
select count(*) from complaints where RID=11120059 and permanent_token <> '0';
```

I'd also recommend the use of `PreapredStatement`s, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

While MySQL will allow both `!=` and `<>`, `<>` is generally more widely accepted by other databases

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
select * from complaints where RID=11120059 where permanent_token !='0';
```

To this:

```
select count(*) from complaints where RID=11120059 and permanent_token <> '0';
```